# Get Error when Save modifed record using Light Switch on Azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure, save, record, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using Light switch on Azure.

After I modified a column in a record when I click the Save button I got

"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows(0). Entties may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded, Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

I use VS 2012 on my dev machine debug this light switch app. it works fine and no errors when I modify the save column on same records then save it.

Is anybody in this forum has idea what could cause this? and how should I work around it?

I suspect the azure machine don't have the same version of EF with my dev machine. but in the Light switch project both client and server reference I could not find the EF is referenced there. So I don't know how I can bring the EF dll on my machine up to Azure machine.

Anybody could give me some suggestion on this?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's a side effect of Optimistic Concurrency. This article can give you the idea of it in Lightswitch:
[LightSwitch 2012 Concurrency Enhancements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2012/07/10/concurrency-enhancements-in-visual-studio-lightswitch-2012-eric-erhardt.aspx)

When it's working on dev machine and it's not working on Azure, I guess something is not right in your production database.

you can also take a look at [Entity framework: affected an unexpected number of rows(0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/entity-framework-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpec)

Comment: When it working on dev machine it is pointed to the production database. In other words On Azure and on my dev machine the LightSwitch app is point to the same database. It works on my dev machine but get that error on Azure.

Comment: And I am pretty sure in the production environment (Azure) there is only one user (myself) using it when the error occurs and no other user changed anything on the record neither through the lightswitch UI or by other means. so there is no concurrent usage of the database during that time frame.

Comment: Is the problem only in updates or you have the same problem for new records? have you deployed it as a website on Azure or it's a desktop app?

Comment: I just tried to add a record for that table in production. and it get the same error message. I also tried it on my dev box to add a record to that table and it is successes. after I added the record through my dev box I tried to delete it from production site and it also got that same error. but I deleted it successes from my dev machine. and it is deployed as cloud service.

Comment: And I also tried to create new record and update in another table it works fine in production the difference between the 2 tables are the table get error has one insert trigger and one update trigger. and it works fine on dev box point to production db which is on SQL Azure

Comment: Is it an "INSTEAD OF INSERT" trigger?

Comment: The insert trigger is after insert trigger the update trigger is instead of update triger

Answer (score 0):

Having Instead of insert/update triggers, sometimes SQL server does not report back an IdentityScope for each new inserted/updated row. Therefore EF can not realize the number of affected rows. 
Normally, any insert/update into a table with identity column are immediately followed by a select of the scope_identity() to populate the associated value in the Entity Framework. The instead of trigger causes this second step to be missed, which leads to the 0 rows inserted error.

You can change your trigger to be either before or after insert or tweak your trigger by adding following line at the end of it:

```
select [Id] from [dbo].[TableXXX] where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [Id] = scope_identity()
```

Find more details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820992/error-when-inserting-into-table-having-instead-of-trigger-from-entity-data-frame/6298870#6298870) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806828/optimisticconcurrencyexception-sql-2008-r2-instead-of-insert-trigger-with-ent) thread.

Comment: In this case could explain what is reason the triggers work fine on Dev box only have the issue in cloud?

Comment: tried adding select [Id] from [dbo].[TableXXX] where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [Id] = scope_identity() still got the same error.

Comment: Can you change your trigger to be either before or after (insert/update)trigger?