# Is it possible to replace SELECT SCOPE_INDENTITY() in INSERT generated statements in EF 6?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

One of my tables in SQL Server, has an InsteadOfInsert trigger defined, which I cannot modify. EF 6, will generate a correct

```
INSERT [SomeTable] ([SomeColumns]) VALUES (SomeValues)
SELECT [SomeIdenityColumn], [ROWID]
FROM [SomeTable]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [SomeIdenityColumn] = scope_identity()
```

but this call fails miserably, due to scope_identity() being null when coming out of the InsteadOfInsert trigger, which I cannot modify. Is there any way in EF 6 to modify the generated SQL to utilize the OUTPUT Inserted approach instead?

**UPDATE**

Found these two on SO:

[OptimisticConcurrencyException -- SQL 2008 R2 Instead of Insert Trigger with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806828/optimisticconcurrencyexception-sql-2008-r2-instead-of-insert-trigger-with-ent)

[error when inserting into table having instead of trigger from entity data framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820992/error-when-inserting-into-table-having-instead-of-trigger-from-entity-data-framew/6298870#6298870)

**UPDATE 2 - AKA REALLY BAD NEWS**

So I have modified the generated SQL code using SSMS in an attempt to utilize INSERT INTO OUTPUT.

```
INSERT INTO [SomeTable] ([SomeColumns]) 
OUTPUT Inserted.[SomeIdenityColumn], Inserted.[ROWID]
VALUES (SomeValues)
```

When executing from SSMS I get this error:

> Msg 334, Level 16, State 1, Line 41 The target table
>   'AuMine.QUOTE_STAFF_ACTIVITY' of the DML statement cannot have any
>   enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without
>   INTO clause.

Classic catch 22 ..

Comment: Seems like I am not the only one: http://bobondevelopment.com/2011/05/26/sql-server-instead-of-trigger-gotchas-revealed/

Comment: The problem description doesn't make sense. [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190315.aspx) is used, specifically, because a trigger has a *different* scope and so no action taken within the trigger should affect its value. Are you sure you've correctly diagnosed the actual issue here?

Comment: Yup, executed the EF generated SQL from SSMS and saw it with my own eyes ... Other posts confirm that using InsteadOfInsert trigger, pretty much kills EF. Apparently it is a known "feature"

Comment: Add just to clarify, I have no control of the trigger, and the trigger does an update on another table, than insert on the original one. SCOPE_IDENTITY() is available withing the trigger, but not outside. It  is simply NULL